# Update data using SQL android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM shopping WHERE modified = 1")
    fun getModify(shopping: Shopping)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun modify(shopping: Shopping)
```

Implementation

```
binding.btl2.setOnClickListener {
            val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "HelloTEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            toast.show()


            viewModel.getModify()
            viewModel.modify(
                Shopping(
                    product = binding.edl1.text.toString(),
                    quantity = binding.edl2.text.toString(),
                    price = binding.edl3.text.toString(),
                    bought = binding.ch1.isChecked

                ))


        }
```

How to implement it well? I have error with viewModel.getModify().
I would like to run these two methods getModify and then modify() after one click.

So program should choose from database only these which are checked as true(1) and then using button modify.

Comment: your `fun getModify(shopping: Shopping)` is just executing a sql statement but because your method doesn't have a return type, it isn't going to return any results to you. room has a variety of return types it supports, pick one which best works for you, see [the section about query methods](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data)

Comment: I tried to use @Insert or @ Update, but unfortunately it doesn't work, nothing happens so I thought it doesn't choose what has to be modified exactly. in that case I should left only @ insert~ but it doesn't work that way..